# How to convert VGA to RGB?

Tags: lcd, converter, rgb, vga

I have an LCD screen whose connector does not have a synchronous pin (according to the photo). I want to connect a laptop to it through the VGA port. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Sync is probably on green. You are probably going to have problems making it work.

Comment: what kind of output does your laptop have? What kind of documentation do you have for your screen? And: what's the thing you want to achieve by connecting this? (and I mean: what's the use case, which resolution, which kind of operation do you need?)

Comment: It looks like relatively simple circuits can produce the necessary sync on green: https://www.raphnet.net/electronique/sync-on-green/sync-on-green_en.php

Comment: How do you know that it takes analog input? Or that that the "-" pins are grounds, or if it takes standard 0.7V 75 ohm signals in?

Comment: VGA is already RGB, but you need to convert the sync signals (probably sync-on-green, as stated). Do you have a manual/datasheet?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply of dear friends. Unfortunately, I don't have a data sheet or a manual for this old LCD

Comment: I want to send from the laptop to the LCD video clip in mp4 format. 1024x1280